# Python: globals().items() iterations try to change a dict

Tags: python, python-import

In `cso.data.__init__.py` I'm trying to do following:

```
from  cso.data._features  import * # import sumbodule 

for k, v in globals().items():
    if isinstance(v, entity):# entity is some type
        print(k,v)
```

To my surprise, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:\Programming\workspaceEclipse\PyCommonSence\src\cso\data\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from  cso.data._features  import *
  File "X:\Programming\workspaceEclipse\PyCommonSence\src\cso\data\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    for k, v in globals().items():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

For some reason it tries to modify the iterated globals somehow. How can it be ?
Is there another better way to list all variables in the form `name: value` from all modules in the package?

The list comprehension equivalent works without error, but prints twice:

```
print([ (k, v) for k, v in globals().items() if isinstance(v, entity)])
```

What is happening here?

Comment: Try `for k, v in list(globals().items()):`.

Comment: i dont want to create new list since i expect there will be lots of items

Comment: How many is "lots"? Anyway see my edit for two alternatives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run code at global scope, the names you assign to are globals too. `k` and `v` are first assigned *after* you begin iterating `globals().items()`, which adds entries for `'k'` and `'v'` in the `globals()` dictionary.

You could avoid this by explicitly copying the `dict` before iterating it, e.g.:

```
for k, v in globals().copy().items():
```

or by doing the work in a function (which will store the iteration variables in local scope):

```
def print_global_entities():
    for k, v in globals().items():
        if isinstance(v, entity):# entity is some type
            print(k,v)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_global_entities()
```

Doing this actually makes your code faster to boot; outside a function, every store to, and load from, `k` and `v` involves a `dict` lookup, while inside a function, Python can (and the CPython reference interpreter does) use simple C array lookups with the indices computed at compile time.

The third approach is the cheaty approach: Make sure `k` and `v` exist beforehand, so the `globals()` `dict` doesn't add or remove items. All you need for that is to add:

```
k = v = None
```

just before the `for` loop.

Comment: yes thats the answer.k = v = None is cool :D Also any ideas why print([ (k, v) for k, v in globals().items() if isinstance(v, entity)]) called TWICE?

Comment: @snamef: It shouldn't, unless you actually run it twice. But you only showed a single line of code, and I can't tell what else you might have done to cause it (or cause something like it, e.g. accidentally nesting a copy of `globals()` into a global that would look almost like a doubled output without newlines to break it up separately).

Answer (score 0):

Because a for-loop statement creates a new variable(s), in your specific case:

```
for k, v in globals().items():
    ...
```

You've created `k` and `v` in the global namespace, which is *literally that dict*

List comprehensions, on the other hand, create their own local function scope. Just do:

```
for k, v in globals().copy().items():
    ...
```

If you don't want to copy, then do:

```
k,v = None, None
for k,v in globals().items():
    ...
```

Or better yet, wrap this all in a function so you don't accidentally touch the global namespace