# How to prevent substring match in dictionary keys?

Tags: dictionary

I am trying to export particular globals to a config file based on a dictionary, but the script keeps exporting partial matches, so if I tried to export a global named "value" it would also export "v", "val" and "a". How to prevent that?

```
data_to_export = {k: v for k, v in globals().items() if k in fields}
```

Comment: Might it be that you accidentally made `fields` a string instead of a list? That would gives substring matching. If `fields` is a list, I don't see how you get the described behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into a problem very similar to this: [Python: globals().items() iterations try to change a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57532675/python-globals-items-iterations-try-to-change-a-dict).

When you perform the `for` loop comprehension, you're creating two new variables `v` and `k` that will then be added to the globals list. Instead, try `{k: v for k, v in globals().copy().items() if k in fields}`

However, I'm not sure what's going on with `a`. Can you provide an example of the exact output you're seeing for that one?

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the issue I have. My issue is not related to the k and v variables, but any variable of name's which a substring named variable exists. For example, if I use this method to export "ply" I will get both "ply" and "y" exported, if "y" is also present in the code. I would like to only export "ply" in this example.